# “System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101”

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

I have SOQL on 17 objects to delete sharing
Need help since we cant use SOSL on _share__c objects

```
list<Lease__Share> deleteLeaseShare = new list<Lease__Share>([select id from Lease__Share where ParentId in: leaseIds and RowCause <> 'Owner']);
if(deleteLeaseShare.size()>0){
    Database.DeleteResult[] srList = Database.delete(deleteLeaseShare, false);
}

list<Rent_Roll__Share> deleteRentShare = new list<Rent_Roll__Share>([select id from Rent_Roll__Share where ParentId in: rentRollIds and RowCause <> 'Owner']);
if(deleteRentShare.size()>0){
    Database.DeleteResult[] srList = Database.delete(deleteRentShare, false);
}


list<Request__Share> deleteRequestShare = new list<Request__Share>([select id from Request__Share where ParentId in: requestIds and RowCause <> 'Owner']);
if(deleteRequestShare.size()>0){
    Database.DeleteResult[] srList = Database.delete(deleteRequestShare, false);
}
```

Can we make it dynamic?

Comment: Are you doing it in a loop?  Can you please post the full code structure?

Comment: You can potentially combine multiple types in a single delete - see e.g, [Conserve DML Statements](http://jessealtman.com/2013/08/conserve-dml-statements/) - but not AFAIK in queries.

Comment: if you have triggers on the deleted sobjects that do soql, they will execute as well